# Multiple imputation with MICE provides twice the expected number of rows

Tags: r, r-mice

I ran the following code to impute 10 data frames of 2120 observations.

I expected to obtain a long dataframe of 10 X 2120 = 21200 observations, but I obtained 42400 observations, as if the whole process ran twice. The first 3 columns look like below.

It is not a big problem because I can subset the first half, but I was wondering if someone had an explanation for this.  Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks

`````
for (group in 0:1) {
  predictor.selection <- quickpred(imputed_df, mincor=0.1, minpuc=0.5,method='pearson',
                                   exclude=c("idme"))
  imputation <- mice(imputed_df, m=10, method="pmm", visitSequence="monotone",
                     predictorMatrix = predictor.selection)
 
  long.imputation = rbind(long.imputation,complete(imputation, action="long"))
} ````

row#   .imp   .id    idme
1       1       1     5001
2       1       2     5002
3       1       3     5003
4       1       4     5004
...
2121    1       2120   8288
2122    2       1      5001
2123    2       2      5002
2124    2       3      5003
...
21200  10      2120   8288
21201   1       1     5001
21202   1       2     5002
21203   1       3     5003
21204   1       4     5004
...
23320   1       2120   8288
23321   2       1      5001
23322   2       2      5002
23324   2       3      5003
...
42400  10      2120   8288
`````

Comment: You go through the loop twice and stack the results with `rbind` so 2 * 21200. I assume you left out the code where you created `long.imputation` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `group` values (`0:1`) is not used in the loop using `lapply`/`replicate` would be a good option.

```
imputed_dataset <- function() {
  predictor.selection <- quickpred(imputed_df, mincor=0.1, minpuc=0.5,method='pearson',
                                   exclude=c("idme"))
  imputation <- mice(imputed_df, m=10, method="pmm", visitSequence="monotone",
                     predictorMatrix = predictor.selection)
  return(imputation)
}

result <- do.call(rbind, replicate(2, imputed_dataset(), simplify = FALSE))
result
```